# printing from nested dictionaries in classes

Tags: python, dictionary

Having isues figuring out why this particular setup isnt working.

```
class market(object):
    def __init__(self, market, coin):
        self.coin = coin
        self.market = market
        req = requests.get(f"http://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market={market}-{coin}")
        sum = requests.get(f"https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummary?market={market}-{coin}")
        self.address = req.json()
        self.marketsum = sum.json()

    def ticker(self):
        while True:
            print(self.address["result"])
            time.sleep(5)

    def marketsummary(self):
        print(f"Market Summary for {coin}")
        print('_' * 20)
        print("Market Name: ", self.marketsum['result']['MarketName'])
        print("High: ", self.marketsum['result']['High']))
        print("Low: ", self.marketsum['result']['Low'])
        print("Volume: ", self.marketsum['result']['Volume'])
        print("Last: ", self.marketsum['result']['Last'])
        print("BaseVolume: ", self.marketsum['result']['BaseVolume'])
        print("TimeStamp: ", self.marketsum['result']['TimeStamp'])
        print("Bid: ", self.marketsum['result']['Bid'])
        print("Ask: ", self.marketsum['result']['Ask'])
        print("OpenBuyOrders: ", self.marketsum['result']['OpenBuyOrders'])
        print("OpenSellOrders: ", self.marketsum['result']['OpenSellOrders'])
        print("Previous Day: ", self.marketsum['result']['PrevDay'])
        print("Created: ", self.marketsum['result']['Created'])
        print("DisplayMarketName: ", self.marketsum['result']['DisplayMarketName'])`
```

Ive previously used this method with static(?jaron?) variables in if statements, such as

```
usdt_ticker = requests.get("https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=USDT-ADA")
btc_ticker = requests.get("https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=BTC-ADA")
eth_ticker = requests.get("https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=ETH-ADA")

print("Which trade pairing would you like for this coin?")
tradepair = input("> ")
if str.lower(tradepair) == "usdt" or "tether":
    actual_ticker = usdt_ticker.json()
elif str.lower(tradepair) == "btc" or "bitcoin":
    actual_ticker = btc_ticker.json()
elif str.lower(tradepair) == "eth" or "ethereum":
    actual_ticker = eth_ticker.json()
else:
    print("Sorry that trading pair isnt currently being monitored by this system")
print("Now viewing Cardano /", str.upper(tradepair), " trading." )
current_price = actual_ticker["result"]["Last"]
```

but with the `self.marketsum['result']['MarketName']` its not working. If theres any input as to why this is happening and how to fix it I would be greatly appreciative. The error I am getting is

`TypeError: list indicies must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: line 77 
`Msummary.marketsummary()`
line 45
        `print("Market Name: ", self.marketsum['result']['MarketName'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [developer's guide](https://support.bittrex.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003723911-Developer-s-Guide-API), the json structure of a response from  `/public/getmarketsummary` looks like:

```
{
    "success" : true,
    "message" : "",
    "result" : [{
            "MarketName" : "BTC-LTC",
            "High" : 0.01350000,
            "Low" : 0.01200000,
            "Volume" : 3833.97619253,
            "Last" : 0.01349998,
            "BaseVolume" : 47.03987026,
            "TimeStamp" : "2014-07-09T07:22:16.72",
            "Bid" : 0.01271001,
            "Ask" : 0.01291100,
            "OpenBuyOrders" : 45,
            "OpenSellOrders" : 45,
            "PrevDay" : 0.01229501,
            "Created" : "2014-02-13T00:00:00",
            "DisplayMarketName" : null
        }
    ]
}
```

Notice the result is actually a list containing a single element. They don't state why it is in a list and I can't get it to return a list with more than one element.

For now, it should be fine to change the lines accessing `marketsum` from

```
self.marketsum['result']['last']
```

to

```
self.marketsum['result'][0]['last']
```

Probably also add a check that the list is not empty.

Comment: This did it! I wish I understood why it worked more clearly but im glad its working none the less haha.

To answer your question, its a list of dictionaries one for each cryptocurrency.

Comment: The `result` object is a list whose only element is a dict. It looks something like `result = [ {'high': 0.13, 'low': 0.12} ]`. To get to the dictionary inside you need to take it out of the list.